# What does "make a big scene out of his misery" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

I have a sentence:

> Rejection in real life is very far from the way it is commonly portrayed in movies, where women often make fun of the unattractive male who shows his interest in them and make a big scene out of his misery.

Do you understand the expression "make a big scene out of his misery"?
Does it mean "through a big scene, he escaped from his misery and make women love him"?

Answer (score 2):

> [make a scene](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make-a-scene)
>   verb phrase
>
> - To exhibit anger, indignation, fiery temper, hysterics, etc, in a public outburst
> - Make a public disturbance or excited emotional display.

So it's saying that the women in the movies use the men's misery to make a public display. Or, they bring attention to the men's misery in a public manner. It's suggesting that the women  use the men's  misery to humiliate them in a public manner.

A "big scene" would simply be a big outburst or disturbance in the definition above.